# Client/server issues with threads. Port already bound

Tags: java

I have to create a distributed system that consists of a server and 4 clients, The server has a file that all client can not read simultaneously, while only one to write in it. Each client chooses randomly whether to read the contents of the file or whether to write to it.

If the client elects to write, it generates a random number between 0 and 911, which is written in the file given to the client the server. A client disconnects from the server
when the random number is 100. You must implement appropriate mechanisms to enable the server to synchronize clients.

Here's the error:

```
Error during I/O
Error during I/O java.net.BindException: Address already in use:
JVM_Bind    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)  at
java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
My_Thread.run(My_Thread.java:18) java.net.BindException: Address
already in use: JVM_Bind    at
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)  at
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)    at
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)  at
java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)    at
My_Thread.run(My_Thread.java:18) Waiting Incoming Connection... Local
Address :0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 Port :5555 Error during I/O
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset  at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)     at
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)  at
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)   at
sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)   at
java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)  at
java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)     at
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)     at
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)     at
Server.main(Server.java:34)
```

Here's the code:

server

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        My_Thread t1=new My_Thread();
        My_Thread t2=new My_Thread();
        t1.start(); 
        t2.start(); 

    try{

    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5555,50);
    System.out.println("Waiting Incoming Connection...");
    System.out.println("Local Address :"+server.getInetAddress()+" Port :"+server.getLocalPort());
    Socket sock = server.accept();
    BufferedReader instream = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (sock.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter outstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
    FileWriter file = null; 
    int number=0;
    try
    {  
          file = new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt");  

    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
          System.out.println("File Error");
    }

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

    String strin = instream.readLine(); <---and heare
    if (strin.equals("Insert")){ //following the protocol

    do{
    //strin = instream.readLine();
    //outstream.write(strin+"\n");
    //outstream.flush();
    number = instream.read();
    file.write(new Integer(number).toString());
    file.write("   ");
    file.flush();
    }while(number!=100); //bye = terminate the conversation
    }else if(strin.equals("Read") ){

        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                   outstream.write(scanner.nextInt());
                   outstream.flush();
                }
    }else { 
    System.out.println("Connection Closing...");
    }
    instream.close();
    outstream.close();
    file.close();
    sock.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error during I/O");
    ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }}}

client

    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{

    Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
    BufferedReader instream = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter outstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
    System.out.println("Sending Messages to the Server...");
    System.out.println("Connecting to "+ sock.getInetAddress()+ " and port "+sock.getPort());
    System.out.println("Local Address :"+sock.getLocalAddress()+" Port :"+sock.getLocalPort());
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    String strin, strout;
    int number=0,choice=0;;
    choice=random.nextInt(2);
    System.out.println("choice "+choice);
    if(choice==1){
    outstream.write("Insert\n");
    outstream.flush();

    do{
    number=random.nextInt(911);
    System.out.print(number);
    outstream.write(number);
    outstream.flush();
    }while (number!=100);

    }else if(choice==2){
    outstream.write("Read\n");
    outstream.flush();

    do{
    number=instream.read();
    System.out.println(number);

    }while (true);
    }

        }catch (Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Connection Refused!!!");
    }
    }
    }

My_Thread

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class My_Thread extends Thread{
    public void run(){

        try{

            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5555,50); <---heare
            System.out.println("Waiting Incoming Connection...");
            System.out.println("Local Address :"+server.getInetAddress()+" Port :"+server.getLocalPort());
            Socket sock = server.accept();
            BufferedReader instream = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (sock.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter outstream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
            FileWriter file = null; 
            int number=0;
            try
            {  
                  file = new FileWriter("C://Users//Vagos//Desktop//file.txt");  

            }
            catch(IOException ex)
            {
                  System.out.println("File Error");
            }

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));

            String strin = instream.readLine();
            if (strin.equals("Insert")){ //following the protocol

            do{
            //strin = instream.readLine();
            //outstream.write(strin+"\n");
            //outstream.flush();
            number = instream.read();
            file.write(new Integer(number).toString());
            file.write("   ");
            file.flush();
            }while(number!=100); //bye = terminate the conversation
            }else if(strin.equals("Read") ){

                while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                           outstream.write(scanner.nextInt());
                           outstream.flush();
                        }
            }else { 
            System.out.println("Connection Closing...");
            }
            instream.close();
            outstream.close();
            file.close();
            sock.close();
            }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error during I/O");
            ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you mark where the error happens?

Comment: And what happens if you try I listen (and connect - don't forget to adjust that!) on another port?

Comment: i marke the lines .......
@11684 i dont understound what you mean..

Comment: How you are allowing 4 Clients to connect to server? You are using `serverSocket.accept()` only once!!

Comment: if i put a 'while(true)' in the class server before the 'Socket sock = server.accept();'

Comment: @Βίκτοραςανδρεάδης Sorry, made a typo. Here's my comment again:  
What happens if you try to listen on (and connect to - don't forget to adjust that!) another port?

Comment: Yes , you should , but you are not doing that. in your code !?

Comment: i change the port and put the while and again give the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind to a port once from your program (unless you set a specific socket option, `SO_REUSEADDRESS`, but ignore that for now). As it is currently, you are attempting to bind a process to the same port three times - once in your for loop, and one time each for the two threads you start up. I'm not entirely sure why you are starting up three server processes, but you will want to revisit your design and make sure you are only binding the server port once.

---

***Edit***:

What I would do is remove the try/catch logic from the main method, and spawn just ***one*** thread:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    My_Thread t1 = new My_Thread();
    t1.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example ,please ?

Comment: i cant reamove the try/catch

Comment: @Βίκτοραςανδρεάδης - why not? Without waiting for a response, if you can't remove the try/catch, then don't spawn off the two threads.

Comment: i cant reamove the try/catch , if i rempve  it all code make it faulse for eclipse, i make it once , i will try it this.